# decoding a chinese stopwords file and appending to a list

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, decode

I am trying to read a chinese stopwords file and append the characters to a list. This is my code:

```
word_list=[]
with open("stop-words_chinese_1_zh.txt", "r") as f:
    for row in f:
        decoded=row.decode("utf-8")
        print decoded
        word_list.append(decoded)
print word_list[:10]
```

This is my output. Decoded looks fine but after i append decoded to a list, it reverts back to the undecoded characters.

```
着

诸

自
[u'\u7684\r\n', u'\u4e00\r\n', u'\u4e0d\r\n', u'\u5728\r\n', u'\u4eba\r\n', u'\u6709\r\n', u'\u662f\r\n', u'\u4e3a\r\n', u'\u4ee5\r\n', u'\u4e8e\r\n']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list hasn't reverted to the undecoded characters. If you print the type of the element in the list:

`>>> print type(word_list[0])`

You'd get:

`<type 'unicode'>`

So there isn't anything wrong with your list. Now we turn our attention to the print function. When you call print on an object, it prints whatever that object's **str** function returns. In the case of a list, however, its **str** function iteratively calls **repr** on each element, which returns the Python representation string of said element instead.

The behavior that you want here is to have **str** invoked instead of **repr** on each element in the list. There is one caveat here: **str** will attempt to encode the given object using 'ascii' encoding, which will invariably fail as the list elements are in unicode. For the purpose of displaying on screen, you likely want whatever sys.stdout.encoding is, and it's usually 'UTF-8'.

Thus, to print a unicode list on screen:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print '[' + ','.join(w.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) for w in word_list) + ']'
```

Alternatively, we can pass in a unicode string and let print deal with the on-screen encoding:

```
>>> print u'[' + u','.join(word_list) + u']'
```

And one last thing: it appears that the elements in your word_list contains newline characters as well. You may want to omit them since you're building a list of stop words. Your final solution would be:

```
>>> print u'[' + u','.join(w[0] for w in word_list) + u']'
```